# Postgis: ST_VoronoiPolygons gives TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection

Tags: postgis

I have a problem that `ST_VoronoiPolygons` started to give me `GEOSVoronoiDiagram: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection`

The function that I use it for have worked for a long time for me.

Comment: That's odd to see; `ST_VoronoiPolygons` essentially interprets its inputs as a `MultiPoint`, no matter what the actual geometry type is, so the concept of validity doesn't really apply.

Comment: I filed a related ticket at https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4335#ticket

Comment: This is caused by a robustness problem in the underlying GEOS library.  This has been fixed and will show up in PostGIS in the next release.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was connected to that the data I had was in a perfect grid. I don't know why but `ST_VoronoiPolygons` couldn't handle it.

So what I did was that I altered the points slightly (I use Python to populate the data so I added `import random` and `+ random.gauss(0.00000001, 0.00000001)` to the x and y coordinate)

Comment: You could probably fix this more elegantly by  using ST_SnapToGrid in Postgis. These sorts of errors are usually caused by spurious precision in geometries, so reducing the number of decimal places generally works.

Comment: Well, I tried with `ST_SnapToGrid`, hence when I used a size "small enough" I got the same problem.

Comment: Exactly. But it is much more deterministic than using random, which could still result in topology exceptions occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there was a self-intersection... Have you tried [ST_isValid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValid.html) and [ST_isValidDetail](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValidDetail.html) functions? The second one could tell you where exactly this intersection is. The simplest way to deal with them is to use ST_Buffer function with radius = 0 - that's because [ST_Buffer](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html) is creating brand new geometry based on origin and this geometry is always valid. With radius 0 you'll get exactly the same geometry but without self-intersections.

Comment: Is `ST_MakeValid(geom)` a better option to `ST_Buffer(geom, 0)`? Seems more intentional.